# In Flutter How to get image path after selecting images using Multi Image Picker?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, imagepicker

I want to get an image path from selected multiple images, I'm using this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) to select multiple images but I got assets, I want paths from selected multiple images because I want to upload into the API.
I added this dependency in `pubspec.yaml` If there any good way to do this, please tell me

```
multi_image_picker: ^4.6.3
```

This is my file upload class, This UI looks similar to Facebook.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';

class UpdateStatus extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UpdateStatusState createState() => _UpdateStatusState();
}

class _UpdateStatusState extends State<UpdateStatus> {
  List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
  String _error = 'No Error Dectected';

  Future<ByteData> byteData;
 // List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create Post'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: InkWell(child: Text('POST',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),onTap: ()
              {
                print('Post this post');
              },),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 300.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: 100,
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          color: Colors.black
                      ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter your Post Details Here !',
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                thickness: 1.0,
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    color: Colors.white70,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0,),
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.add_a_photo,),
                            Text("  Choose Image",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,),),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: ()
                        {
                          print(images.toList().toString());
                          print('choose image from local');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    thickness: 1.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    color: Colors.white70,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0,),
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate,),
                            Text("  Choose Video",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,),),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: ()
                        {
                          print('choose video from local');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Divider(
                thickness: 1.0,
              ),
         Container(
           height: 200,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(child: Text('Error: $_error')),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Pick images"),
                    onPressed: loadAssets,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: buildGridView(),
                  )
                ],
              ),
         ),
         /*
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(child: Text('Error: $_error')),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Pick images"),
                onPressed: loadAssets,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: buildGridView(),
              )
            ],
          ),

              */
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> loadAssets() async {

    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    String error = 'No Error Dectected';

    ByteData byteData;


    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 300,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
          actionBarTitle: "Ilma",
          allViewTitle: "All Photos",
          useDetailsView: false,
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
        ),
      );

    } on Exception catch (e) {
      error = e.toString();
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
      _error = error;
      print('000000000000000000000');
      print('000000000000000000000');
      print(images);
      print('000000000000000000000');
      print('000000000000000000000');
    });



  }

  Widget buildGridView() {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
        Asset asset = images[index];

        byteData=asset.getByteData();

        print('0000');
        print(byteData);
        print('0000');



        return AssetThumb(
          asset: asset,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        );
      }),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: how do you upload your data? using `http` package? or `dio`? or anything else?

Comment: I'm using `http` package, Thank you, I hope you will help me

Comment: so you have the raw bytes to upload (`asset.getByteData()`), dont you? whats the problem then?

Comment: if I print byteData `print(byteData);` i got this out put `Instance of 'Future<ByteData>'`,

Comment: see https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAS0EQuM-oU

Comment: What do I want to do now?

Comment: you want to check the links i posted

Comment: yes, I'm waching

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209658/discussion-between-prasath-and-pskink).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(
                'POST',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
              onTap: () async {

 List<MultipartFile> multipart = List<MultipartFile>();

                for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                  var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(images[i].identifier);

                }   

              },
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm Using below Code to **select multiple images** by using **file_picker: ^2.0.7** Library.
Long press to select multiple image.   Once Image Selected you can use **f** arr to display the images.

```html
List<File> f = List();

 RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Pick Image"),
            onPressed: () async {
              FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                allowMultiple: true,
                type: FileType.custom,
                allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'],
              );
              if (result != null) {
                f = result.paths.map((path) => File(path)).toList();
                setState(() {});
                print(f);
              }
            },
          ),
```

[image]

Sample API Call For image upload and normal data. Image uploaded column should be arr ( photo[] ).

```html
 List<MultipartFile> newList = new List<MultipartFile>();


Future<String> ImageUpload() async {

var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
 request.headers["Authorization"] = pref.getString("token");
    request.headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
   //Image Data
  for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
      newList.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('photo[]', f[i].path));
    }
    request.files.addAll(newList);
    
    Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, String>();
    //normal data
    data["user_id"] = user_id;
    data["project_id"] = pro_id;
    
    request.fields.addAll(data);
    var res = await request.send();
    
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      debugPrint("Status${res}");
      }else {
      debugPrint("status code${res}");
      }
      
    }
```

```
Try This You can select and upload multiple images easily. Thank you.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **multi_image_picker 4.7.14** library to pick  Multiple Images. use below code you can send selected asset image as a file. `

```html
//Inside Widget Builder
FlatButton(
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/camera.png",
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            onPressed: loadAssets,
          ),
          
    SizedBox(
                  // height: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 10,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: buildGridView(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

```html
List<File> fileImageArray = [];
  List<String> f = List();
  List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
  List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
  
  Future<void> loadAssets() async {
    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 4,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
          actionBarTitle: "Example App",
          allViewTitle: "All Photos",
          useDetailsView: false,
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
        ),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      error = e.toString();
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    for (int i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) {
      var path =
          await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(resultList[i].identifier);
      print(path);
      f.add(File(path));
    }

    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
    });

    // return fileImageArray;
  }

//image PreView
  Widget buildGridView() {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
        Asset asset = images[index];
        return AssetThumb(
          asset: asset,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

API Call : while image uploading place use multipart file

```html
List<MultipartFile> newList = new List<MultipartFile>();
    
  Future<String> multiImagePostAPI() async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
    request.headers["Authorization"] = pref.getString("token");
    request.headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
    
     for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
      newList.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('photo[]', f[i].path));
    }
    request.files.addAll(newList);
     Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, String>();
      data["user_id"] = user_id;
      data["project_id"] = pro_id;
      data["title"] = titleController.text;

      request.fields.addAll(data);

      var res = await request.send();
     
     if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      debugPrint("Status$res");
     }else {
      debugPrint("status : $res");
      }
      
     
     }
```

Comment: did this but i got an error which says   ``E/flutter (16058): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Can't finalize a finalized MultipartFile.``, i followed through on exactly what you did,please lhelp

Comment: please check the library version. because this version is old, may be version problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also select multiple images using **file_picker: ^1.5.0+2**  library and easy to get path of selected images

```
Future<int> getFilePath() async {
try {
  files = await FilePicker.getMultiFile();
  if (files == '') {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    setState(() {
      this._filePath = files;
      return 1;
    });
  }

} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print("Error while picking the file: " + e.toString());
}
```

}

> show selected images by using ListView Builder like this

```
               ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: _filePath.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,c)
              {

                return Card(
                  child: Image.file(_filePath[c],
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    width: 400,
                    height: 400,

                  ),
                );
              }
          ),
```