# Flutter - How to get gallery folder path?

Tags: flutter

I want to get gallery folder path.

I tried to use multiple libraries `[path_provider, storage_path, image_save, multi_image_picker ...]` to get the gallery folder path, but none of the libraries got the gallery folder path.

Comment: What is your end goal, to get the path, or to get the file from gallery?

Comment: save image & video and check file exists

Comment: Try this https://pub.dev/packages/storage_path

Comment: He has tried it @Filip Same has been mentioned in his question :)

Comment: @Alok I guess it's impossible to get the path to the gallery itself. If I understand the gallery correctly, it is something like the application itself, and you can get only the path to the folders contained in it or the files themselves.

Comment: Yeah, even I am trying to figure something out for this @Filip It is fairly impossible to do that right now, but there is always a work around which can be followed. Hence I am searching for it.

Comment: @Alok  Plase check this answere  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61011335/12037365

Answer (score 0):

See, I don't find any great thing to save your file to your gallery, what I did found is to how to get your things done.

My solution will give you some things like

- Save a file visible to the user
- Check whether the file exists or not

**Saving the file:**

- For saving the file we can rely on the package [downloads_path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider).
- Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59629863/5362583) answer for using this package precisely
- [Flutter save file visible to the user - StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59154031/flutter-save-file-visible-to-the-user) would help you to know how he is using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package to save his files.

**Check whether the file exists or not**

To do this, you can use this code inside your code, where you are trying to save the file, form the above answer.

**Important:** *You will get the `path` of the file where you are storing the file, just pass the path in the below code*

```
import 'dart:io' as io;

// for a file
bool exists = io.File(path).exists();

// for a directory
bool exists = io.Directory(path).exists();

if(exists) // do your operation
else // do your else operation
```

I am able to produce this much content for your problem. Any feedback are welcomed.

Comment: worked on android but error on IOS
please see bug:
https://imgur.com/ZP1Mz6l

Comment: Yeah @HưngTrịnh  so `iOS`, I have already shared the answer, in which he has mentioned what to do for iOS as well. This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59629863/5362583. It is already there under **Saving the file** `Point number 2`.  Let me know if that works out for you :)

Comment: i use ```getApplicationDocumentsDirectory``` from **path_provider** . File saved but it not in gallery. path save current: ```on Iphone > myapp > image_download. ```

Comment: That means you are able to get what you want, right @HưngTrịnh ?

Comment: no, now file has downloaded and can view on system app: ```File```
but i want to save image and view image on gallery

Comment: Yeah, that is why I mentioned that thing, that I came up with this sorta solution, cos this is the best which is available for you. You can keep exploring your way to search for the desired result. Till the time, you can make use of this answer. Thanks @HưngTrịnh :)